# Task could not find "AL.exe" TFS 2013

Tags: winapi, resx

I'm using Windows 7 SP1 and Visual studio Ultimate 2013. TFS server 2013 is installed in Windows Server 2008.

Below error occurred while trying to build one solution which supports multilingual resx files:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets
>   (3001): Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the
>   registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the
>   SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor
>   specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft
>   Windows SDK is installed

I have gone through similar questions, but those solutions didn't work. Few are given below:

1. Install Windows SDK

   - Windows SDK is already installed
   - `al.exe` is present in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools`
   - `al.exe` is present in `\Windows\v7.0A\bin and v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools`
2. Remove resx files and build

   - Resx files are part of the project and I want them to be in my build.

Any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Why not set the SdkToolsPath in your environment and reboot/relog?

Comment: Well, that looks like a giant mess.  Unraveling this is going to require you being a lot more detailed about exactly how you installed and what your build commands look like.  At least check if the 32-bit version of MSBuild runs okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your comments. I installed Windows SDK in server machine, where TFS is installed. It solved my problem.