# Project containing .resx files - build failure on server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have project in my application containing only resource files, one default "en-GB" and the other "cy-GB". The solution builds on my local machine but fails when pushed to the build server for publishing with the following error:

> [AL] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3266, 5): error MSB3086: Task could not find "AL.exe" using the SdkToolsPath "" or the registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\NETFXSDK\4.6\WinSDK-NetFx40Tools-x86". Make sure the SdkToolsPath is set and the tool exists in the correct processor specific location under the SdkToolsPath and that the Microsoft Windows SDK is installed

When I look on the build server (Windows 2008 R2) this registry key doesn't exist. The .NET Framework 4.6 has been installed and has been building fine until the introduction of this new project. I have read numerous previous posts on similar issues:

[MSBuild on CI Server can't find AL.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986440/msbuild-on-ci-server-cant-find-al-exe)

[Task could not find "AL.exe" TFS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26905563/task-could-not-find-al-exe-tfs-2013)

**Could someone point me in the right direction? Could this be a problem with my solution or possibly something missing from the build server hence the registry key not being there?**

Comment: Why don't you just have your RESX files in your web project so that Al.exe is no longer required.

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492155/failing-build-because-it-cant-find-al-exe

Comment: Would have the same issue if these files were in the web project. Thanks for the post. I hadn't seen this and will scour for some further info.

Comment: @JimmyB Do you install Windows SDK for windows 2008? https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=11310